# Best practice to download files by WPF Client?

Tags: wpf, http, silverlight-4.0, download

I have a Silverlight 4.0 website where users can upload images. (Users have to login in order to upload files.)

Also I have some  WPF Client which downloads those images using HTTP.

My question is:

Have do I create some simple ASP .NET MVC 3 website to realize it or there is a way that WPF Client can login and download images? I mean, if I have to use Silverlight website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the url for the images, just use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), I did something like this using the code below:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
//image url
var bytes = wc.DownloadData(url);
//the MemoryStream is used to convert to BitmapImage to WPF Image Control
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

var img = new BitmapImage();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
img.BeginInit();
img.StreamSource = ms;
img.EndInit();
```

Comment: Yes... That's correct. But I mean if I have to get URLs from Silverlight website or MVC3 website, or just have access to the folder over HTTP?

Comment: you don't need an application if you have the IIS configured correctly to access these folders with the right permissions...

Comment: simple put the files in a folder inside IIS (default is C:\inetpub\wwwroot ) an then try to access the url in localhost (maybe you have to create a Site in IIS)

Comment: change the permissions of the folder to public access